# Есть форма HTML, в ней очень много полей, нужно данные из формы преобразовать в XML файл

Tags: php, xml

Есть ли возможность все данные из формы перевести в XML, не выводя каждое значения input через $_POST

Comment: Пройтись  циклом по инпутам $_POST?

Comment: А как затем преобразовать в XML полученный массив?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.createelement.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Alpha
Сделал так :

```
/* create a dom document with encoding utf8 */
    $domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    /* create the root element of the xml tree */
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("one");
    /* append it to the document created */
    $xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);
    //пройдёмся по массиву $_POST
foreach($_POST as $post_key=>$post_val){
    //создание элемента XML с названием из ключа $_POST массива и его значения
     $currentTrack = $domtree->createElement($post_key, $post_val);
     //добавление значения ребенка к элементу выше 
    $currentTrack = $xmlRoot->appendChild($currentTrack);

}
```